# Crude image clustering using a Caffe model?

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, deep-learning, caffe, vision

Let's say I have a Caffe Model that can recognize textures. Is there a straightforward way to get a crude segmentation of an image using the classification results for a sliding window?

Comment: if you can get a rough "per-pixel" class from sliding window texture classification, you can use graphcut optimization to make a global, coherent labeling of the image pixels. "CRF optimization" is the term you need googling.

Comment: Would this require retraining an existing model? If I have a model trained for patch sizes of say 256x256 on a variety of textures, and I use this to estimate a per pixel classification using a bounding box on that pixel, I can then use graphcut to clean up the result into coherent regions?

Comment: basically, if you have  a classifier that outputs a "per-pixel" prediction, taking the most likely label per-pixel usually looks very un-smooth. Taking the -log of the per-pixel predictions as a unary-term for CRF combined with simple per-wise smoothness term should give you a smoother and more consistent output.